# XML не читается Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Есть заданная форма xml. Внешняя часть выглядит так

И дальше этой части он не читает, хотя есть множество вложений. Если убрать всю информацию во внешней части он начинает читать все остальные вложения. Как считывать XML без потери информации во внешней части?
Использую ElementTree

Так информация после name не считывается и при print(getroot) выводит <Element '{name3/name.xsd}name' at 0x0000000002A35720>

```
<name xmlns="gogle/name.xsd" xmlns:xsi="name2.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="name3/name.xsd"> 
    <Craft>315</Craft> 
    <StartingSIP>95</StartingSIP> 
    <StartingSIPTime>2021-09-23T10:03:55</StartingSIPTime> 
    <Starting>1356</Starting>
    <Sessions> ...... </Sessions> 
</name>
```

Если сделать так весь остальной xml считывается

```
<name> 
    <Craft>315</Craft> 
    <StartingSIP>95</StartingSIP> 
    <StartingSIPTime>2021-09-23T10:03:55</StartingSIPTime> 
    <Starting>1356</Starting>
    <Sessions> ...... </Sessions> 
</name>

trees = ET.parse(filename)

    root = trees.getroot()

    for i in root:
        print(i)
```

и выводит он

```
<Element 'Craft' at 0x0000000002A95EA0>
<Element 'StartingSIP' at 0x0000000002A95DB0>
<Element 'StartingSIPTime' at 0x0000000002A95770>
<Element 'Starting' at 0x0000000002A95C20>
<Element 'Sessions' at 0x0000000002A95B80>
```

Comment: Ошибок не выдаёт при выводе print(getroot) выводит последний элемент <Element '{http://name3/name.xsd}name' at 0x0000000002A35720>.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите минимальный xml, на котором воспроизвоится ошибка..

Comment: < name xmlns="http://gogle/name.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.name2.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://name3/name.xsd">
    <Craft>315</Craft>
    <StartingSIP>95</StartingSIP>
    <StartingSIPTime>2021-09-23T10:03:55</StartingSIPTime>
    <Starting>1356</Starting>
    <Sessions>
    ......
    </Sessions>
</name>

Comment: Вся нижняя информация будет выводиться если сделать так
< name> 
<Craft>315</Craft> 
<StartingSIP>95</StartingSIP> 
<StartingSIPTime>2021-09-23T10:03:55</StartingSIPTime> 
<Starting>1356</Starting> 
<Sessions> ...... </Sessions> 
</name>

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/cG9j4xWzq  - вроде нормально разбирается.

Comment: Тут ошибка не в ссылке на namespace, а в пробеле между скобкой и name `< name` - это действительно неваличный xml.

Comment: В файле xml пробела нет

Comment: Посмотрите документацию Parsing XML with Namespaces. <https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces

Comment: Спасибо! пойду разбираться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from lxml import etree

xml_raw = """<name xmlns="gogle/name.xsd" xmlns:xsi="name2.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="name3/name.xsd">
    <Craft>315</Craft>
    <StartingSIP>95</StartingSIP>
    <StartingSIPTime>2021-09-23T10:03:55</StartingSIPTime>
    <Starting>1356</Starting>
    <Sessions> ...... </Sessions>
</name>"""
root = etree.fromstring(xml_raw)
for elem in root.getchildren():
    if not elem.text:
        text = "None"
    else:
        text = elem.text
    print(elem.tag + " => " + text)
```

Вывод:
{gogle/name.xsd}Craft => 315

{gogle/name.xsd}StartingSIP => 95

{gogle/name.xsd}StartingSIPTime => 2021-09-23T10:03:55

{gogle/name.xsd}Starting => 1356

{gogle/name.xsd}Sessions =>  ......

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('1.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
    print(child.tag, child.text)
```

Вывод:
{gogle/name.xsd}Craft 315

{gogle/name.xsd}StartingSIP 95

{gogle/name.xsd}StartingSIPTime 2021-09-23T10:03:55

{gogle/name.xsd}Starting 1356

{gogle/name.xsd}Sessions  ......

1.xml

```
<name xmlns="gogle/name.xsd" xmlns:xsi="name2.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="name3/name.xsd">
    <Craft>315</Craft>
    <StartingSIP>95</StartingSIP>
    <StartingSIPTime>2021-09-23T10:03:55</StartingSIPTime>
    <Starting>1356</Starting>
    <Sessions> ...... </Sessions>
</name>
```

Comment: Да второй способ подходит, но в <Sessions> есть вложения <Session> их он не может прочитать.

Comment: Что значит не читается? Ты как то код для этого доработал?

Comment: Я пошаманил и получилось добраться до значений Session через root[4]. По итогу нужно разбираться с пространственными именами, что бы было всё максимально правильно) спасибо!